# How to run a .bat file in a VM from Powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, virtual-machine

I am trying to parallelize an operation by running .bat files in several remote VMs simultaneously using a Powershell script from a local VM.  I can successfully run the .bat file in the local VM by using the following:

```
Start-Process cmd.exe -ArgumentList  $batOptimization_path, $vmNumberParam, $rInstanceParam, $optDataParam, $dataSetParam
```

The first param in -ArgumentList is the path where the .bat file is located, the rest are command line parameters for the .bat file.  To try to run the .bat file on a VM, I am using the following:

```
$psSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $script:FsvRConfig.VmList[$i].IpAddress
Invoke-Command -ArgumentList $batOptimization_path, $vmNumberParam, $rInstanceParam, $optDataParam, $dataSetParam `
                       -Session $psSession `
                       -ScriptBlock {Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Start-Process cmd.exe  -ArgumentList $args[0], $args[1], $args[2], $args[3] -AsJob}} `
                       -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

This does not run the .bat files properly.  The jobs start and then fail, so obviously this is not the way to launch the jobs.  Any advice on getting the .bat files to launch in the remote VMs the way it does in the local VM would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are the batch files? Are you sure it is not the batch-files that have an error?

Comment: Open up a Command Prompt window, `cmd.exe`, type `help cmd` or `cmd /?` and read the usage information presented. You should notice, pretty must straight away, that, if you're going to specifically use `cmd.exe` directly, _(probably not necessary)_, that you should at least be using one of either `/C`, _(Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates)_, or `/K`, _(Carries out the command specified by string but remains)_. That means the first argument in your `-ArgumentList` would be one of those, _(most likely the former)_. You may also need to take care with any quoting too!

Comment: The batch files fire off R scripts that I wrote that all work fine when I invoke the Start-Process command in my original post.  I am just trying to fire off in remote VMs those scripts that work fine in local VMs.

Comment: The parameter  $batOptimization_path already includes /k in the path.  Again, as I originally wrote, the batch file runs just fine in the local VM.  I just need it to now work in a remote VM.  I use cmd just so I can see the output of the analysis without having to waste the resources of opening an instance of RStudio or Visual Studio.

Comment: For clarity, this is how the path variable is declared: $batOptimization_path = [IO.Path]::Combine('/k ' + $remoteFsvrBatPath, "RMAT_Optimization.bat")

Comment: $remoteFsvrBatPath is just a path on my local VM (all remote VMS use the same directory structure, so no issue there)